# Права на запись в /var/log

Tags: linux, безопасность

У меня есть сервис на спринге, и в нем сконфигурирован логгер logback на запись в директорию /var/log/my_service_name. При запуске сервиса под кроном получается ошибка записи логов permission denied. Нет прав доступа к директории у юзера, от которого запускается сервис. Как проще всего разрешить запись в /var/log из-под крона?

Comment: заведите в /var/log отдельную папку и установите на нее права для нужного пользователя. так делает большинство приложений исполняющихся не под root

Comment: @Mike, я сделал sudo chown my_user /var/log/my_service, но это не помогло

Comment: @Mike, если сделать sudo -u my_user, тоже permission denied

Comment: тогда вариантов всего 3: 1. не достаточно прав на то что бы войти в каталог /var или /var/log для этого пользователя (отсутствует 'x' для всех) (маловероятно, вход в каталог в большинстве систем есть по умолчанию). 2. на вашем каталоге нет прав на запись владельцем (которого вы вроде как установили) 3. сервис работает не под тем пользователем, под которым вы думаете